# Should we design interfaces to include object manipulators

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I have a class named `ValidationResult` which implements `IValidationReport`. These are generic entities which are meant to encapsulates output of the various validators we have. All validators do return `IValidationReport`.

As a  standard design practice we include only getters in `IValidationReport`, and no setters or methods that can manipulate the contents of the returned object. Thus it has `getResult(String filePath)`, `getMessages(String filePath)` etc. which returns validation result, validation messages and other information of validation of the specified file.

`ValidationReport` have different overloads of the form `addResult(filePath, message, ...)` which adds the corresponding information against specified `filePath`. However we also have one method in `ValidationReport` called `addResult(IValidationReport)`. This method essentially work as merging two `ValidationReport`s. So if two validation reports (the on which this method is called and the one which is passed as an argument) have validation information of same file, then it will be merged.

Now in one of our modules, it happens that we are calling two validators. Both have `validate()` methods which returns `IValidationReport`. However I cannot merge the two as `IValidationReport` contains only getters, but `addResult(IValidationReport)`. That is following:

```
IValidationReport valrep1 = validator1.validate();
IValidationReport valrep2 = validator2.validate();
valrep1.addResult(valrep2); //cannot do this as valrep1 is IValidationReport and it does not contain addResult(IValidationReport)
```

- So what should I do? Should I be adding `addResult(IValidationReport)` to `IValidationReport`. But then it will break design convention of not adding object manipulators to interfaces.
- Where did I go bad with the design? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

I think a better practice would be to have a ValidationResult(IValidationReport... reports) constructor.

```
ValidationResult valResult = new ValidationResult(validator1.validate(), validator2.validate())
```

or something along those lines :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple helper to merge the results and then return a new instance of your interface.

```
public class ReportHelper {

public static IValidationReport merge(final String filePath, final IValidationReport r1, final IValidationReport r2){

    return new IValidationReport(){

        public String getResult(String filePath){
            // Merge here r1.getResult(filePath) and r2.getResult(filePath)
            //...
            return "The merged content";            }

        public String getMessages(String filePath){
            // Merge here r1.getMessages(filePath) and r2.getMessages(filePath)
            //...
            return "The merged content";
        }
    };
}
```

As your helper returns a IValidationReport you can use its result like any other report without breaking your standard design practice.